# Корректность сочетания "богат на"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Корректно ли употреблять на русском языке фразу "богат на...", например, "вчерашний день был богат на события"? Или же только "вчерашний день был богат событиями". Первый вариант мне кажется украинизмом.

Answer (score 1):

**богатый**
(обладающий чем-либо в большом количестве) ***чем*** и ***на что*.**

**Богатая** полезными **ископаемыми** страна.
Пахло таяньем снега... отошедшими от стужи деревьями, — **запахами**, которыми **богата** в эту пору тайга (Лидин).
Тур, **богатый на голы** (из газет).
[**Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь**](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/94/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Оба варианта одинаково возможны:
*вчерашний день был **богат событиями*** и *вчерашний день был **богат на события***.

*Октябрь **богат на** голевой урожай!

Астролог: Август будет **богат на** затмения

Август **богат на** свежие овощи

2007 год от Р.Х. **богат** для Русской Православной Церкви **на** юбилеи, кратные ста.

Это неудивительно, поскольку он **богат на** достопримечательности и интересные места...*

Правда, следует отметить, что "богат на" употребляется реже.